# How do I add minutes to a time data type?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure which inserts two records into a table, the difference between the records is that the time column of the second record is `@MinToAdd` after the first:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateEntry
    /*Other columns*/
    @StartTime time(2),
    @EndTime time(2),
    @MinutesToAdd smallint
    AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @MinutesToAdd = @MinutesToAdd % 1440;   --Prevent overflow if needed?
    IF (@MinutesToAdd > 0)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ClientNotification (/*Other columns*/ startTime, endTime)
        OUTPUT inserted.id
        VALUES
               (/*Other columns*/ @StartTime, @EndTime),
               (/*Other columns*/ @StartTime + @MinutesToAdd, @EndTime + @MinutesToAdd);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        /*Whatever ELSE does.*/
    END
END
```

What is the correct way to add `@MinutesToAdd` minutes to `@StartTime` and `@EndTime`?
Please note I am using the `time` data type.

**Update**:
A correct answer should contain the following information:

- How to add minutes to to a `time` data type.
- That the proposed solution does not result in a loss of precision.
- Issues or concerns to be aware of in the event that the minutes would be to too large to fit in a `time` variable, or risk of rolling the `time` variable over.  If there are no issues then please state so.

Comment: I don't see how your edit to your question further clarifies the question at hand.

Comment: @swasheck I explicitly state the three things I am looking for.  I also set bounds on what I am not looking for.

Comment: http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/899/regarding-the-authors-right-to-edit-his-own-question

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can't use lazy shorthand arithmetic with the new types. Try:

```
DATEADD(MINUTE, @MinutesToAdd, @StartTime)
```

Note that even though you have protected your `@MinutesToAdd` from overflow, you haven't protected the result from overflow. This doesn't yield an error, however, just might not be the result you're expecting.

```
DECLARE @StartTime TIME(0) = '23:59';
DECLARE @MinutesToAdd INT = 20;

SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @MinutesToAdd, @StartTime);
```

Result:

```
00:19:00
```

I assume this must go through some type of internal conversion, because you couldn't get that result by saying:

```
DECLARE @StartTime TIME(0) = '24:19';
```

Result:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

You need to consider how you want to handle calculations that lead to either `@EndTime` or both `@StartTime` and `@EndTime` to be in the next day.

Also - to address another new requirement in your "ideal answer" - there is no loss of precision. As per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), the return type of `DATEADD` is the same as the input:

> The return data type is the data type of the *date* argument, except for string literals.

Therefore, `TIME` in, `TIME` out.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use dateadd function to add your minutes in integer against '0:00'. Then cast back to time.

Select cast(dateadd(minute,84,'0:00') as time)

Here, 84 is the integer minute I want to be expressed in "time" type.

I added that to '0:00' and then to remove the date component, I castes it to time type. No custom coding necessary.

### (No column name)

01:24:00.0000000