# Which terms are used to refer a row in database?

Tags: database-design, table, naming-convention, row

I am creating a Java application, in which I want to create a class that will relate to a row in database.

I decided to use `Entity` while naming the class with a prefix/suffix. But,
This [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html) says:

> An entity is a lightweight persistence domain object. Typically, an **entity** represents a **table** in a relational database, and each **entity instance** corresponds to a **row** in that table.

I am too conscious & put much time while naming classes, packages etc.

So, what are the other terms, a row in a database can be referred with?

Comment: A row is a row. There is no other name for it. Some people use the term "record", but as [Joe Celko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Celko) put it: "*Rows are not records; fields are not columns; tables are not files*"

Comment: I think, his statement states that "In DBMS terminology a row should not be called a record". But, when a row has been retrieved & transformed into a bean instance that you app holds, it can be referred as a record. That's what I understand from this [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31850/63579). Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right to use `Entity` name for prefix/suffix to represent a table schema as your class Entity is a mapping to table schema not the data of the table.

And in terms of data mapping a single instance of the Entity will always represent the row as the row will have all those columns which are attributes in entity and a List of the Entity will represent a table.