# What is the difference between a field and a column?

Tags: relational-theory, table, fields

Although I have always regarded the terms as interchangeable, I have read somewhere that they’re not the same. I suppose this means that a record is not exactly the same as a row either.

I teach that the main difference is how you visualise the data — it is a column if you think of a table, but a field if you think of a form.

What is the real difference between them, and to what extent does it matter?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between a “record” and a “row” in SQL Server?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31805/what-is-the-difference-between-a-record-and-a-row-in-sql-server)

Comment: I would say that a field is a specific intersection of a row and column.

Comment: @JonathanFite: FWIW, I call that a cell.

Comment: Call them rows and columns here. Call them whatever you want elsewhere